# Check a SWF's Flash Version and ActionScript version from Python?

Tags: python, django, actionscript, flash

I need to validate an uploaded SWF to ensure it meets certain Flash and ActionScript version limitations. Anyone know a good Python library to parse metadata out of a SWF?

Comment: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/hexagonit.swfheader

Answer (score 0):

Hexagonit.swfheader checks Flash version, which is part of Michael's question, but doesn't cover ActionScript version, does it?

Answer (score 0):

Finding the target flash version is easy, it's just the 4th byte:

```
file.seek(3)
print ord(file.read(0))
```

"ActionScript version" can mean multiple things.

If you just need to know whether the SWF is ActionScript 3 or not, read the "actionScript3" property of the FileAttributes tag.  You could probably do this yourself pretty easily if you read the SWF specification.

If you need to know the numeric version of the ActionScript 3 code, e.g. "46.16", one exists for each DoABC tag in the file.  This would probably require a library for parsing the entire SWF.  I don't know of any good ones for python.